# How can i load nested folders for FreeMarker template using spring org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean

Tags: spring, freemarker

Hi I have requirement to create ftl for different entities,

I want to load ftl's from nested folders, Like all A realted ftl's should be insite A folder then all the Macro's live into Macro folder.

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:freemarker/Account/"/>
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

this is not working.Using spring 4

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath"> 
        <value> "classpath:freemarker/Account/" , "classpath:freemarker/Macro/"</value>
    </property>
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Also after debugging the spring class

```
public void setTemplateLoaderPath(String templateLoaderPath) {
    this.templateLoaderPaths = new String[] {templateLoaderPath};
}
```

Instead of an array , templateLoaderPath behaves like single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `templateLoaderPaths` property (note the `s` at the end), not `templateLoaderPath`.

I believe the Spring syntax for that will be (haven't tested it...):

```
<property name="templateLoaderPaths"
          values="classpath:freemarker/Account/,classpath:freemarker/Macro/"
/>
```

or the longer form:

```
<property name="templateLoaderPaths">
  <array>
    <value>classpath:freemarker/Account/</value>
    <value>classpath:freemarker/Macro/</value>
  </array>
</property>
```

Comment: (Mark it as an answer then.)